# Duplicate resource tab with ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resources, model, activeadmin

I've got a User resource that I'm using ActiveAdmin to display.  Is it possible to add two instances of that same User resource so that I could customize the columns differently in each one?  If so, will running the generator for that resource clobber the existing files that were already created?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can rename the resource which will allow you to have a duplicate resource tab:

"By default, any references to the resource (menu, routes, buttons, etc) in the interface will use the name of the class. You can rename the resource by using the :as option."

Example:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post, :as => "Article"
```

The resource will then be available as /admin/articles.

http://activeadmin.info/docs/2-resource-customization.html#rename_the_resource

Comment: I think the issue here is that the generator makes several things.  I'm pretty sure if I generate another User resource tab, it'll clobber the original.

Comment: Actually, it won't even let me generate a duplicate resource tab.

Comment: Adding the admin resource manually under a different name did it.

Answer (score 0):

You can duplicate *app/admin/users* by different name like that *app/admin/users_abc* and use *as: "#{name}"*

```
ActiveAdmin.register User, as: "Users"

ActiveAdmin.register User, as: "Users Abc"
```

It works for me!

Comment: Although the post was so long ago, but I still commented for someone who see this problem :D